# I need to scrape the job description text for every job title in the mentioned page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape the job descriptions in the page () for every job title like section (accounting) job title (staff accountant) job description text inside the title in different columns in a csv file using python beautiful soup module.

I'm new to beautiful soup i tried some ways of doing it but its not working can you please help with the code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

start = time.time()

url = ""
data = []
while True:
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'lxml')
jobdesc = soup.find("li",{'class':'col-xs-12 col-sm-4'})
section=soup.find("h4")
jd = {"jobdescription":jobdesc.text,"topic":section.text}
data.append(jd)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("JD.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way leveraging :has in bs4 4.7.1+ to isolate the sections for looping over. zip_longest is used so we can join section title on to each job.

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from itertools import zip_longest

r = requests.get('https://resources.workable.com/job-descriptions/#', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

with open("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:

    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(['Section','Job Title'])

    for section in soup.select('section:has(.job)'):
        title = section.select_one('a').text.strip()
        jobs = [job.text for job in section.select('li a')]
        rows = list(zip_longest([title], jobs, fillvalue = title))
        for row in rows:
            w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Below are the error i got while running the code                                                TypeError: file() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given),'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function,UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Yes i run it as is i'm usning python 2.7 so i just changed zip_longest to izp_longest other than that no changes

Comment: Ah... the problem must be the with open.... line due to being python 2.7. Remove the encoding argument

Comment: code is running fine but it is not returning any data in data in python 3 also ,and i need section job title and job description also but it is showing empty columns of Section Job Title
 only these two

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Are you now running in python 3?

Comment: i'm running it in both python 2.7 and python 3 ,in both cases i'm getting an empty data.csv file only

Comment: if you add print (row) in before w.writerow(row) are you seeing the data is retrieved?  I have tested this and runs fine this end.

Comment: Did you see data when print(row) ?

Comment: It is printing when print(row) is given like this (u'Accounting', u'Staff Accountant ') (u'Accounting', u'Night Auditor ')                                                                          But it is not writing data into csv file it is giving "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)"  Another thing is i need job description text inside the job title i.e for example staff accountant job description not just job title .I think you understand what i'm saying and thanks for your efforts.

Comment: It must be something to do with your locality as it gives me a csv with two columns perfectly. I will have to research this and get back to you. What encoding does the page have that you are viewing?

Comment: document.characterSet
"UTF-8"                                                                                                                
 and one more imp thing the code returning only job title and related job section but i need job description as well in 3rd column is it possible

Comment: the job description doesn't come from that page. It would mean visiting each of the links for the jobs. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes, i need 3 columns containing job section (Ex.Accounting) ,job title (Ex.Staff accountant),job description (text inside the staff accountant job title) like wise for all of them in that page

Answer (score 0):

I had a 403 forbidden using `requests` package, so I decide to use `selenium`

You can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://resources.workable.com/job-descriptions/#"
data = []
#resp = requests.get(url)
#soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
section = soup.find_all('section',{'class':'box-white'})
for s in section:
    title = s.find('h4').text
    lis = soup.find_all("li",{'class':'col-xs-12 col-sm-4'})
    for li in lis:
        jd = {"jobdescription":li.text,"topic":title}
        data.append(jd)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("JD.csv")
```

**EDIT: To get description for all jobs**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://resources.workable.com/job-descriptions/#"
data = []
#resp = requests.get(url)
#soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
section = soup.find_all('section',{'class':'box-white'})
for s in section:
    title = s.find('h4').text
    lis = s.find_all("li",{'class':'col-xs-12 col-sm-4'})
    for li in lis:
        job = li.text
        driver.get(li.find('a').get('href'))
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        jd = {"job":job,"topic":title, "description": soup2.find('div',{'class':'entry-content article-content'}).text}
        data.append(jd)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("JD.csv")
```

Comment: Sorry it is returing an empty csv file ,can you please check it once fix it please@ Maaz

Comment: @praveen check the `soup` object if the information are inside. It is working for me. HAve you any stacktrace?

Comment: soup element have                                                                                         <html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr/><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>                                                                                                                                and it is returning empty csv file at the end

Comment: Are you running the code using selenium or requests? Because it was the content I receive using requests

Comment: it is with Requests

Comment: @praveen So test it with selenium, it should work properly

Comment: Yeah its working but the thing is i need job description text inside the job title i.e  i need 3 columns containing job section (Ex.Accounting) ,job title (Ex.Staff accountant),job description (text inside the staff accountant job title) like wise for all of them in that page

Comment: @praveen to do this you have to scrap all other pages. See my edit :-) (plus I did an error scraping the titles, it is fixed now ;-) )

Comment: @praveen you're welcome, so please accept the answer and up the response then ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Scraping data from monster jobs and uploading to Mongo DB.

```
from time import *
from selenium import webdriver
import pymongo
from pymongo.results import InsertManyResult
import os


client = pymongo.MongoClient()
mydb =  client['jobs']
collection  = mydb['med_title']

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/91798/Desktop/pythn_files/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.monsterindia.com/")

driver.implicitly_wait(9)
driver.find_element_by_id("SE_home_autocomplete").send_keys("nursing , Therapist , docter , medical ,nurse , hospital")

#for normal search use this 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='themeDefault']/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input[1]").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
temp = 1
while(True):
    if temp == 5:
        break
    all_jobs =  driver.find_elements_by_class_name("card-apply-content")
    link_list = []
    for job in all_jobs:
        try:
            company = ""
            com_name = job.find_elements_by_class_name("job-tittle")
            driver.implicitly_wait(1)
            for ele in com_name:
                company = ele.find_element_by_class_name('company-name').text
            job_title = ""
            for ele in com_name:
                job_title = ele.find_element_by_class_name('medium').text
       
            location = job.find_element_by_class_name("loc").text
            driver.implicitly_wait(1)
            lnks= job.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
            for lnk in lnks:
                link_list.append(lnk.get_attribute('href'))
                break
            driver.implicitly_wait(1)
            desc = job.find_element_by_class_name("job-descrip").text
            driver.implicitly_wait(1)
            skills = job.find_element_by_class_name("descrip-skills").text

        except:
            desc =  'desc Not Specified'
            skills =  'skills Not Specified'  
            location = ' location Not Specified'
            company = 'company  Not Specified'
            job_title = 'job_title not specified'
        
        s = skills.split(' ')
        for i in s:
            if i == ',':
                s.remove(',')
        data = {"job_title" : job_title ,"comapany_name": company,"job_location": 
        location,"job_desc":desc,"skills":s[2::],"card_link":link_list[0]}
        link_list.clear()
        y =  collection.insert_one(data)
        print(y.inserted_id)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Next')]").click()
    sleep(25)
    temp = temp +1
```

Comment: Mind providing details about what your code does and how it will solve the issue? This is VLQ.

Comment: ok sir this is my first post please don't mind